# is there a reliable, repeatable way to check on health of WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking

I live in a apartment with two other people, and about 30 WiFi devices overall. My roommate does a lot of fiddling with technology and has recently brought home a succession of two new cable modems and three or four new wireless routers.

At some point a few weeks ago, it became obvious that my WiFi connection is unreliable. But it's not bad all the time. And sometimes the data rate might seem okay, but a Skype call is broken up by constant dropouts.

In all cases that the WiFi wasn't working, I switched my laptop to my phone as a hotspot and the trouble vanished.

So I suspect there's something wrong in our Wifi. The trouble is that my roommate has made upwards of a dozen changes when you count hardware and configuration changes just in the past two weeks, so we can't narrow it down very well. And the troubles appear and disappear intermittently, so it's not easy to do a quick experiment to change one thing and see if the trouble is permanently gone.

I need a reliable way to test the health of the system after making changes to our Wifi routers and configurations to narrow down the cause. Is there a way I can diagnose the health of my laptop's Wifi connection in a way that would reveal not only current trouble but a sign that could point to intermittent trouble as well?

Comment: Probably not practical for to the setup difficulties, but (on a Linux) wifi connected box you could run nagios + pnp4nagios or cacti and find/write plugins to monitor and graph performance. You probably want to monitor ping times and packet loss, and reported said signal to noise ratio. Ideally, if you can enable SNMP on the router or otherwise get bandwidth utilization that is useful to.  Of-course, you can probably just run a batch if tests periodically from your computer (MTR and wifi signal stats( and compare normal and not.

Comment: 30 devices are quite a lot. Do you have only a single network? That may not be enough, especially with many devices transmitting and receiving at the same time.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. We have other Macs, Windows laptops, and even a Raspberry Pi hooked up, but my roommates have most of the devices, and I have the most trouble on my MacBook Pro. I was reading about Wireless Diagnostics and Wireshark. I'm experienced with a lot of tech, but I'm not a network maven. Is there a guide to diagnosing WiFi problems using those two programs that isn't too complicated?